# Inno Setup, show a msgbox on the folder selection step

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to display a message box only when the user reach the folder selection page, here are the actual code that display the message box at the beginning of the setup:

```
[code]
var ApplicationPath: string;

function GetAppPath(Param: String): String;
begin
RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\XXX\XXX', 'Install Dir', ApplicationPath)
  if ApplicationPath = '' then
    begin
    MsgBox('Install folder non found', mbError, MB_OK);
    result:=ApplicationPath;
    end
    else
    MsgBox('Install folder found in "' + ApplicationPath + '". NOTE: close the program before proceeding.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    result:=ApplicationPath;
    end;
end.
```

I need something like:

If (PageId = wpSelectDir) then...
**[run the above code]**

but really I don't know how, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal event for this is the [`CurPageChanged`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#CurPageChanged). You can use it this way to run a code, when the select directory page is shown:

```
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  AppPath: string;
begin
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectDir) then
  begin
    // this will query the string value in registry; if that succeed and the
    // value is read, then the message box about success is shown, otherwise
    // the error message box about failure is shown
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\XXX\XXX', 'Install Dir', AppPath) then
      MsgBox('Installation folder found...', mbInformation, MB_OK)
    else
      MsgBox('Installation folder not found...', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this event runs both when the page is first reached, and whenever it is returned to.  That includes if the user moves Next past the page and then returns Back to it -- and when returning Back they would not want their previous selection to be overwritten.  As a result it's usually a better idea to do any auto-population tasks from the `NextButtonClick` of the previous page instead.

Comment: @Miral, good point! Next button event might be more user friendly for this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if i put the code like this:

[code]
var ApplicationPath: string;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectDir) then
  begin
    // HERE THE ABOVE CODE "function GetAppPath(Param: String): String;" etc. etc.
  end;
end;


it gives me an error, it's not correct

Comment: You need to move just the code of your `GetAppPath` function there. Not the whole function with its header. But now looking on the `GetAppPath` function again, what is the real purpose of it ? If you're going to find a directory where your application was previously installed and additionally you want to tell the user to close this application before continue, then all this is already built-in in InnoSetup.

Comment: Yes, I know that inno setup automatically search for the proper folder, but this is an add-on for a program of which setup wasn't built with inno setup.
Anyway, I tried but I always get an error if I move the code inside your suggested procedure, could you please modify your answer and show me how to correctly write it? Many thanks

Comment: I've included a script which shows a message box, but doesn't use the global `ApplicationPath` variable. If is used, for instance to determine the target installation path, then you'll need to use it again and remove my `AppPath`. I'd need to see the whole script since the code from your question is cut of the context.

Comment: In the [setup] section I have:
DefaultDirName={code:GetAppPath}

so the installer will use the path to the folder found into the registry, otherwise, if not found, it will be blank

Comment: I see, but note, that you shouldn't interact with the user from directive value functions. Remove from your `GetAppPath` function the message box parts and keep there just that part which query the registry. The message boxes show just from the event functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot TLama, but I think I will keep the initial solution, with the msgbox displayed at the beginning of installation, I am not so skilled in programming :)